# For each loop to add all population

Tags: java, arraylist

I don't know what to do with "For each loop".

i am trying to add up all the population.

i keep getting an error with the for each loop.

the error says " cannot applied to given types"

can someone please help me with this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Canada
{
    private ArrayList<ProvinceTerritory> provinces;

    public Canada()
    {
       provinces = new ArrayList<ProvinceTerritory>();

       provinces.add(null);
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("Ontario",12851821));
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("Quebec",7903001));
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("British Columbia",4400057));
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("Alberta",3645257));
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("Manitoba",1208268));
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("Saskatchewan",1033381));
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("Nova Scotia",921727));
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("New Brunswick",751171));
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("Newfoundland and Labrador",514536));
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("Prince Edward Island",140204));
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("Northwest Territories",41462));
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("Yukon",33987));
       provinces.add(new ProvinceTerritory("Nunavut",31906));

    }

    public int getTotalPopulation()
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for(ProvinceTerritory tempT : provinces)
        {
            if (tempT != null)
            {
                sum += tempT.getPopulation();
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

and here is the "ProvinceTerritory" class code

---

```
public class ProvinceTerritory
{

    String  name;
    int     population;

    public ProvinceTerritory(String name, int population)
    {
        if(name != null)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("cant be null");
        }

        if(population >0)
        {
            this.population = population;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Can not be -ve");
        }    
    }



    public String getName(String Province)
    {
        if (Province != null)
        {
            this.name = Province;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("cant be null");
        }
        return this.name;
    }


    public int getPopulation(int People)
    {
        if (People >0)
        {
            this.population = People;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("cant be -ve");
        }
        return this.population;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: remove this line " provinces.add(null);"

Comment: Can you please edit your post and copy-paste the complete, unabbreviated compiler error?

Comment: The code you've posted is fine. Show your ProvinceTerritory class.  You probably don't have a `int getPopulation()` method in it

Comment: Please, next time you edit your question, post the code as code-formatted text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have an `int getPopulation()`. This is why you get an error when you try to call `tempT.getPopulation()`

Instead you have a `int getPopulation(int)` that weirdly tries to act as both a setter and a getter at the same time.

You could have called it with `tempT.getPopulation(0)`, but it would be better to just replace it with a normal getter:

```
public int getPopulation()
{
    return this.population;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked out. sorry for the poor posting. this was my first time.